# C#.NET Core : Cannot deserialize JSON string

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize my JSON string result form a Rest-API Service call, into my own class:

Received JSON-String:

```
{
  "valid": true,
  "messages": [
    "Bank code valid: 065656"
  ],
  "iban": "CH65765756756756756",
  "bankData": {
    "bankCode": "083243",
    "name": "Banque of America",
    "bic": "VZTRCH98XYY"
  },
  "checkResults": {
    "bankCode": true
  }
}
```

My target class:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class IBANValidationResult
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Valid")]
    public bool Valid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Messages")]
    public List<string> Messages { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "IBAN")]
    public string IBAN { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "BankData")]
    public BankData BankData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CheckResults")]
    public CheckResults CheckResults { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class BankData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "BankCode")]
    public string BankCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "BIC")]
    public string BIC { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class CheckResults
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "BankCode")]
    public bool BankCode { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code where i try to deserialize the json-string into my class:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(reqUri))
{
    using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
    {
        var data = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var jsonObj = JSONConverter.DeserializeObject<IBANValidationResult>(data.Result);
    }
}
```

I tried already a few approaches to solve the problem, but I always get the same error message:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
> into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OttosWebAPI.Models.Validation.IBANValidationResult]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'valid', line 2, position 10.

Can anyone tell me, what am I doing wrong here?

Thx

Comment: Things I notice reading your code: 1) You're not awaiting the async operations. You should be awaiting the `*Async()` methods and not using `.Result`. 2) Your JSON and your `[JsonProperty]` attributes differ in naming because they have different cases. One or both may be masking issues.

Comment: Yeah I know i dont await, but since i am debugging in the backend, it does not matter if i wait or not.

Comment: Then why bother making it async?

Comment: I wanted to add the await later, when I am finished with the coding.

Comment: Debugging or not, it's not functionally correct, so you might create other issues that make it harder to solve your original problem.

Comment: Of course you are right, I now added the await key. But I also solved the problem, I had to use the NewtonSoft JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> method. Then it works. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that I should use the NewtonSoft DeserializeObject Method like bellow:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(reqUri))
{
    using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
    {
        var data = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IBANValidationResult>(data.Result);
    
    }
}
```

This works!

Sorry I was to fast for submitting a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Your string casing is all over the place with some lower, some camel-case etc.

> By default, property name matching is case-sensitive. You can specify
> case-insensitivity. If the JSON contains a value for a read-only
> property, the value is ignored and no exception is thrown.
> Taken from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to)

Check that first and then see how it goes. The error says Line 2 Position 10 so that seems to be the first issue.